# Замыкание scala

Tags: scala

```
def Search2(word:String,str:String):Int={
  str.indexOf(word)
}
```

У меня есть функция для поиска первого вхождения подстроки. Как написать замыкание, каждый вызов которого возвращал бы очередной индекс вхождения подстроки в строку? Если слова закончились, то вернуть nil.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типа такого?

```
  def indexes(word: String, text: String): () => Int = {
    def indexOf(word: String, text: String, from: Int = 0): Int = text.indexOf(word, from)
    var fromIndex: Int = 0
    var wasEvaluated: Boolean = false
    () => {
      if (fromIndex != -1) {
        if (wasEvaluated) {
          fromIndex += word.length
        }
        fromIndex = indexOf(word, text, fromIndex)
        wasEvaluated = true
      }
      fromIndex
    }
  }

  val fun = indexes("om", "om om am om")
  for (i <- 0 until 5) println(fun())
```

Результат: 0 3 9 -1 -1

Тут должна быть или функция, возвращающая коллекцию (в этом случае можно вернуть Nil в смысле пустого списка), либо же стоит возвращать числа, в этом случае вместо `Nil` (который типа `List[Nothing]`) логично возвращать `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

```scala
var index = 0
val func = () => {
  val start = word.r
    .findFirstMatchIn(str.drop(index))
    .map(_.start + index)
    .getOrElse(-1)
  if (start != -1) 
    index = start + word.length
  start
}
```

Похоже на вариант Mikhail Ionkin, только приправлено опшионами

P.S. Советую присмотреться к `word.r.findAllMatchIn(str)`, он возвращает не индексы, но возможно это именно то что Вам нужно